# Sum of list item inside dictionary json pytjon

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a json  like the following:

```
{
  "fields": {
    "List1": [
        "List2": [
          {
            "List3": [
              {
                "item": "1",
                "sale": 1149.99
              },
              {
                "item": "2",
        "sale": 20
              }]}]]}}
```

I am using this recursive method to return the sum of the list:

```
def sale_sum(json):
    sale_list=[]
    if isinstance(json, dict):
        for k, v in json.items():
            if k == 'sale':
                sale_list.append(v)
            elif isinstance(v, list):
                for e in v:
                    sale_sum(e)
            elif isinstance(v, dict):
                sale_sum(v)
                
    for i in range(0, len(sale_list)): 
        sale_list[i] = int(sale_list[i]) 
    return sum(sale_list)
```

But I keep getting 0 from the outcome. What's wrong with the code? And is there a better way of doing this?

Update:

made changes to this and still getting 0. I need the sale_list inside the function so I made a nested function.

```
def sale_sum(json):
    sale_list=[]
    
    def list_count(json):
        if isinstance(json, dict):
            for k, v in json.items():
                if k == 'sale':
                    sale_list.append(v)
                elif isinstance(v, list):
                    for e in v:
                        list_count(e)
                elif isinstance(v, dict):
                    list_count(v)
                
    for i in range(0, len(sale_list)): 
        sale_list[i] = int(sale_list[i]) 
            
    return sum(sale_list)
```

Comment: You're recursively calling `sale_sum()` but you're ignoring the returned value.

Comment: You should move `sale_list=[]` outside the function `sale_sum`.  It gets initialized to empty every time you all the function `sale_sum`.

Comment: json is invalid as well. You can check it with an online json parser.

Comment: @Martin I put the sale_list=[] outside the function but still getting 0

Comment: You never call `list_count` in your new code.  Put a call to `list_count(json)` right before the `for i in range(0, len(sale_list)):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myjson = {
  "fields": {
        "List1": [
            { "List2": [
              {
                "List3": [
                    {
                        "item": "1",
                        "sale": 1149.99
                    },
                    {
                        "item": "2",
                        "sale": 20
                    }
                ]
              }
            ]}
        ]
    }
}


def sale_sum(json):
    sale_list=[]

    def list_count(json):
        if isinstance(json, dict):
            for k, v in json.items():
                if k == 'sale':
                    sale_list.append(v)
                elif isinstance(v, list):
                    for e in v:
                        list_count(e)
                elif isinstance(v, dict):
                    list_count(v)
    list_count(json)
    for i in range(0, len(sale_list)):
        sale_list2[i] = int(sale_list[i])

    return sum(sale_list)

print(sale_sum(myjson))
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://gist.github.com/douglasmiranda/5127251) is probably what you are looking for.

Update:

Here is a code example

```
def find(key, dictionary, sale_list):
    for k, v in dictionary.items():
        if k == key:
            yield dictionary
            sale_list.append(v)
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            for result in find(key, v, sale_list):
                yield result
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for d in v:
                if isinstance(d, dict):
                    for result in find(key, d, sale_list):
                        yield result

sale_list = []
list(find("sale", data, sale_list))
print(sum(sale_list))
```